# How to convert dot to comma in smarty

Tags: prestashop, smarty

Good morning,

Prestashop 1.6 in tpl file I have something like this

```
{assign var=groupPrice value=$psoft[0]['price']|number_format:2:",":"."}
<span class="price groupPrice">{$groupPrice*0.23+$groupPrice|number_format:2:".":","}</span>
```

The results is 456.34 (for example). How to convert this dot to comma?

Thanks for help.
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

you can use that :

```
math|replace:".":","
```

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
number_format:2:".":","
```

Replace the first dot to comma. You'll get the result:

```
number_format:2:",":","
```

Comment: Have you cleared Smarty cache and forced compilation in Advanced Parameters-> Performance?